# Angular Radio Input unchecked on load with ng-value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-value to set a radio inputs value to an object so when the value matches the ng-model object it should result in the radio being checked. Here's an example and plunker.

```
<script>
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.Obj = {
    "id": "1",
    "value": "green"
  };
  $scope.ObjTwo = {
    "id": "2",
    "value": "red"
  };
  $scope.ObjThree = {
    "id": "3",
    "value": "blue"
  };

  $scope.modelObj = {
    "id": "3",
    "value": "blue"
  };

}]);
</script> 

<form name="myForm" ng-controller="testController">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="modelObj" ng-value="Obj">
   {{Obj}}
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="modelObj" ng-value="ObjTwo">
    {{ObjTwo}}
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="modelObj" ng-value="ObjThree">
    {{ObjThree}}
  </label><br/>

  color = {{modelObj}}<br/>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/aAISUTEqdGkpVrEJt0uq?p=preview

It seems to work fine when clicking the radio buttons as the modelObj is updated to the relevant object. But why isn't the third radio input(objThree) checked on load? I thought because $scope.Objthree is equal to $scope.modeObj as set in the controller that it would check the radio input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/J3QQM0z0nSC9KulHzQGI?p=preview

Try `$scope.modelObj = $scope.ObjThree;`. This will set the reference of `$scope.modelObj` equal to the `ObjThree` object, rather than just creating a new object with a new reference that happens to have the same properties. In general, JavaScript uses referential equality to compare objects and only uses value equality to compare elementary data types, such as numbers and strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can to set in [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

```
ng-init="modelObj = ObjThree"
```

Could be:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="testController" ng-init="modelObj = ObjThree">
```